# When i open an img with img.show() notepad opens

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library, notepad

I'm trying to make a game in python, and when i display an image with img.show() it shows a notepad with some funky letters.

I've tried saving the image,putting the show before the image.

```py
def crop_center(img):
    return img[0:32,0:32]

def load_image( infilename ) :
    img = Image.open( infilename )
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )
    return data

def save_image( npdata, outfilename ) :
    img = Image.fromarray(npdata,"RGB")
    img.save('my.png')
    img.show()
save_image(crop_center(load_image("spredsheet.png")),"mini.png")
```

I wanted the image to be shown on a separate window.

Comment: Can you post the image you are seeing? And where (what library) is the class `Image` from? What exactly does `img.show()` do?

Comment: The likeliest cause is probably `dtype="int32"`. Try removing that.